# virtual monitoring interface on wifi card

Tags: wifi, network-interface, iwlwifi

I only have one wifi nic in my computer, but I want to be able to monitor all traffic while still connecting to a network.

I was thinking (if it is possible) to have a physical interface `wlan0` connected to the wifi network, and a virtual interface `v0` in monitor mode, both using the same nic. Is anything like this possible?

My wifi card uses the iwlwifi driver.

Answer (score 0):

If your hardware device supports monitor mode then nothing stands against that.

I use the well known TP-LINK TL-WN722N wifi adapter in a Kali machine without any other network interface and have `wlan0` and `mon0`(after adding it as monitor interface) as network devices.